# Moq Transaction Scope in C#

Tags: c#, moq, transactionscope

Is there any ways to moq a transaction scope in order to ensure that commit, complete or rollback operations are called during a process?

Given this function :

```
public void DoSomething(int param)
{
    using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        factory.DoSomething(param);
        factory.DoSomethingElse(param);

        transactionScope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Is there any ways to call a Verify function over the IDisposable interface? It only seems to contain a Dispose function and I would like to test the Commit or the Rollback.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) is sealed class and derived only from `IDisposable` interface.
As I consider, you need to make your own wrapper class for `TransactionScope`  and interface, so you can use and mock it.

```
class TransScopeWrapper : ITransScope, IDisposable
{
    private TransactionScope scope;

    public TransScopeWrapper()
    {
        scope = new TransactionScope();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        scope.Dispose();
    }
    public void Complete()
    {
        scope.Complete();
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        ...
    }
}


internal interface ITransScope
{
    void Complete();
    void Rollback();
}
```

Also you need to inject a `ITransScope` mock somehow. I would make it following way

```
public void DoSomething(int param)
{
    using (TransScopeWrapper transactionScope = new TransScopeWrapper ())
    {
        DoSomething(param, transactionScope);
    }
}

internal void DoSomething(int param, ITransScope transaction) 
{ 
    factory.DoSomething(param);
    factory.DoSomethingElse(param);

    transaction.Complete();
}
```

So now you can test `DoSomething(int param, ITransScope transaction)` method mocking the `ITransScope`.